# Give injecting object as argument to services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm trying to dynamically give the Logger service the name of the resolving class (or the resolving class instance itself) using dependency injection, as hinted in the code below. Is this even possible using Symfony DI, I could not find a solution to that.

Thank you in advance!

*services.yml*

```
services:
    // ...
    MyLogger\Logger:
        arguments: ["%className%"] // is it possible to do sth. like this?
```

*Logger.php*

```php
class Logger
{
    public function __construct(string $className)
    {
        $this->className = $className;
    }

    public function log(string $message)
    {
        echo "{$this->className}: {$message}";
    }
}
```

*MyClass.php*

```php
use MyLogger\Logger;

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        // Should echo: "MyClass: Called getFoo()"
        $this->logger->log("Called getFoo()");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing within the Symfony dependency injection component that will do this sort of thing for you.  It is possible that [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) might provide the info you need.

Comment: Maybe you could [create your own processor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/processors.html) based on Monolog's [IntrospectionProcessor](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/45ebc699ae3ce3896708a2c9399bae4034f89718/src/Monolog/Processor/IntrospectionProcessor.php#L17)